PyQt6 Project dll not found
When trying to start my main, i get this error message:
PS D:\Visual  Studio Code\helloApp> & "d:/Visual  Studio Code/helloApp/.venv/Scripts/python.exe" "d:/Visual  Studio Code/helloApp/main.py"
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
file:///D:/Visual  Studio Code/helloApp/UI/main.qml:2:1: Cannot load library D:\Visual  Studio Code\helloApp\.venv\Lib\site-packages\PyQt6\Qt6\qml\QtQuick\Controls\Basic\qtquickcontrols2basicstyleplugin.dll: The specified module could not be found.

My main.py:
import sys
import os
from PyQt6.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PyQt6.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
from PyQt6.QtQuick import QQuickWindow

QQuickWindow.setSceneGraphBackend('software')
app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
engine.quit.connect(app.quit)
engine.load('./UI/main.qml')
sys.exit(app.exec())

main.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls.Basic
ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 600
    height: 500
    title: "HelloApp"
    Text {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "Hello World"
        font.pixelSize: 24
    }
}

I'm new to coding and i followed a tutorial.
I installed PyQt6 in a venv enviroment
I tried searchin for the .dll and also rename the one that was there.

The message is giving you the path to where the module should be, so you need to establish why it is not there. Were you in the venv when you installed it?

on Linux usually it needs to install C/C++ library Qt to use Python module PyQt - and sometimes it needs to download it from Qt web page

@OldBoy, I was in the venv and there is a file that has a very similiar name (qtquickcontrols2basicstyleplugin.dll). But the other file is still missing, even after reinstalling it.

@furas I'm on windows.

A file with a similar name is not good ebough, it must be the exact same name for the system to recognise it. And if you have installed the correct file then you should be able to find out where it has been stored.

@OldBoy I reinstalled it again and now the file is there, but it still doesnt recognize it and throws the same error

Sorry, but it is impossible for me to guess what may be wrong. If you have installed the package correctly then it should be in the directory listed in the error message. If it is not there then you need to find out where it has been installed.
